# Is it possible to reverse ssh to a system behind a router via a third system if port forwarding is disabled on the middle system?

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel

I want to access a workstation in my lab from my laptop in my hostel room. But I can't directly ssh to the machine as both my laptop 
(in my hostel) and the worstation are behind two different routers to which I don't have access.

But both the workstation and my laptop in my hostel can ssh to a third server, on which I have a non-sudoer account. Firstly, I tried 
to set up this server to forward the ssh connection in gets on a particular port(8088) to the workstation:

```
ssh -vvv -N -T -R 8088:localhost:22 <my-username@the-server>
```

But this did not work, and the follying debug messages show that the server has disabled port forwarding.

```
    debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:8088 forwarded to local address localhost:22
    debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
    debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
    debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
    debug1: Entering interactive session.
    debug1: Remote: Server has disabled port forwarding.
    debug1: remote forward failure for: listen 8088, connect localhost:22
    Warning: remote port forwarding failed for listen port 8088
    debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

What can I do to what I want? Port Forwarding is disabled. Does this not mean that ssh tunneling is not possible on this system? Does 
that also mean that it is not possible to ssh to the workstation from my room?

Comment: If you need access to your work machine, please work with your IT department. Helping people subvert policy isn't something that we help people with here.

Comment: @EEAA I don't mean to cause any trouble. I am doing a yocto build on the workstation which will take hours to complete. So it would be nice if I can check if the compilation stopped due to an error fix it from my room. I don't want to bring up the matter with the Campus Networking Center as I intend this only as a matter of convenience. Moreover it is not a company but a college. So if I make a request, it will take them days to accept it, by which time my work would be over.

Comment: Why don't you have IPv6?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, we still use IPv4 around here. Will it matter in anyway?

Comment: Since it makes bizarre workarounds like this completely unnecessary and restores the end-to-end connectivity we used to have in the very early days... yes. This is the sort of scenario that makes IPv6 evangelists.